# Scroll doesn't work on mobile - it hits the buttons inside the list

Tags: html, css

I have a list with buttons and has a max-height. On desktop, you can scroll through the options, but on mobile, when you try to scroll, it hits one of the buttons and it doesn't want to scroll.

When I remove the buttons and replace them with simple li tags, the scroll works.

So my guess is that the buttons prevent the scroll somehow, but I don't know how to fix it.

Edit: having z-index: -1; makes the div scrollable, but the actual buttons cannot be clicked that way.

Here's my Minimal and reproducible example:

```css
.scroll-area {
  max-height: 1rem;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-area">
  <button type="button" class="multiselect-option dropdown-item" title="Example 1">
         <span class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="example1">. 
              <label class="form-check-label">Example 1</label>
         </span>
</button>

  <button type="button" class="multiselect-option dropdown-item" title="Example 2">
         <span class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="example2">. 
              <label class="form-check-label">Example 2</label>
         </span>
    </button>

  <button type="button" class="multiselect-option dropdown-item" title="Example 3">
         <span class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="example3">. 
              <label class="form-check-label">Example 3</label>
         </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: What should we do with the HTML you posted?

Comment: well, that's the html I use...

Comment: Why in the HTML you use you don't have a closing `</button>` tag? How should we reproduce the issue? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: I fixed it. that's pretty common problem with lists with buttons, nothing special happening in the code. simple html list with buttons that has max-height. Can be tested only on real devices or browerstack. Browser emulators cannot reproduce this issue.

Comment: What's `<label>` doing inside a `<button>` Element? That's invalid HTML markup

Comment: It shows text next to the styled button. the input is hidden

Comment: What's `<input>` doing inside a `<button>` element? That's also invalid HTML markup.

Comment: I also updated the description of the topic. the problem is the z-index of buttons and the scroll area, I just don't know how to fix it. either way buttons or scroll don't work

Comment: Please be opened to learn. Meanwhile please point me to some documentation that says that it *is valid* to have `INPUT` or `LABEL` elements enclosed inside a `BUTTON` Element. And afterwards I think you might want to post some CSS - if that's your other main issue.

Comment: can you share the css and stuffs? we would not be able to help you with the html alone.

Comment: @keysl shared it, it's only one line with max-height

Comment: OK, but - You should 1. **absolutely fix your invalid HTML markup**. 2. post a [mcve] - if the issue still persists.

Comment: @CritingZ If its a one line I think you should add `overflow` property to your `.scroll-area` at the desktop it will rely natively at the window so you will be able to scroll.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan if you copy paste the code you will get the same issue, as I said, that's how mobile browsers treat scroll when there are buttons inside

Comment: Firefox 87.0, Windows 10: I'm not seeing anything? I'm seeing a disabled scroll bar and that's it... Is that the problem?

Comment: @CritingZ on mobile any Action Element will steal the scroll intent. You could use JS to 1. on touchstart detect the initiator Element currentTarget, 2. detect if page is scrolled 3. on touchend see if the scroll was out of Npx and if false trigger a click - Anyways, at least after fixing the invalid HTML.